# VBA code to lookup value in range and return cell across value

Tags: excel, vba

I am hoping someone could help me out with a line of code that I can not figure out.   VBA coding is not my strong point.  The workbook that this code is from will auto email the addresses in column M.  It then pulls in data from other cells in that row that are used in the subject line and body.  Where I am having an issue is the value that will be in Column H of the row.   That value that will be in that cell is a users ID.  That user ID can be found in Range("A2:A18") of the Users worksheet.  The users email address, which is the value I am looking for, is located in Range("B2:B18") of that same sheet. The excerpt from the code below that this applies to is "Please email your closeout documents to: " & Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim strbody As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("M").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value) = "yes" _
       And LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value) <> "Sent" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = Cells(cell.Row, "AD").Value
            .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "AC").Value & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & strbody & _
            "Your closeout package for " & Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value & "/" & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & "/" & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value & "/" & Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value & " is over 30 days past due." & vbNewLine & _
            "All closeout requirements are attached for your reference and due within 10 days of construction complete. Please email your closeout documents to: " & Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value & _
            "• Scheduled Construction Start Date - " & Cells(cell.Row, "X").Value & vbNewLine & _
            "• Construction Start Date - " & Cells(cell.Row, "V").Value & vbNewLine & _
            "• Construction Completed Date- " & Cells(cell.Row, "W").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "• General Contractor - " & Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value & vbNewLine & _
            "• GC Name - " & Cells(cell.Row, "O").Value & vbNewLine & _
            "• GC Phone Number - " & Cells(cell.Row, "P").Value & vbNewLine & _
            "• GC Email - " & Cells(cell.Row, "Q").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "• Company - " & Cells(cell.Row, "J").Value & vbNewLine & _
            "• Name - " & Cells(cell.Row, "K").Value & vbNewLine & _
            "• Phone Number - " & Cells(cell.Row, "L").Value & vbNewLine & _
            "• Email - " & Cells(cell.Row, "M").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

            .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value = "Sent"
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps use `Application.Vlookup` to return the email address based on a lookup of the ID.

Comment: @BigBen  I had tried using vlookup but kept getting errors.

Comment: @Grags - show us what you tried with vlookup and where it fails (or how) and we can help straighten it out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use `Application.Vlookup` to lookup the email address based on the id, something like the following:

```
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Dim emailTo As Variant
emailTo = Application.Vlookup(Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value, Sheets("Users").Range("A2:B18"), 2, False)

... "Please email your closeout documents to: " & emailTo ...
```

Note that `Application.Vlookup` will return an error value if the vlookup is unsuccessful, so you can test the result using `IsError(emailTo)`.